# My API is all returning Future[Option[T]], how to combine them nicely in a for-compr

Tags: scala, scalaz

All of my API methods return Future[Option[T]], trying to figure out how to elegantly perform the following:

```
case class UserProfile(user: User, location: Location, addresses: Address)
```

The below code currently doesn't compile because user, location, and address are all Option[User], Option[Location] and Option[Address]

```
val up = for {
 user <- userService.getById(userId)
 location <- locationService.getById(locationId)
 address <- addressService.getById(addressId)
} yield UserProfile(user, location, address)
```

I remember that scalaz has OptionT but I have never really used it before and not sure how to apply it to my situation.

If say user, location or address actually return None, what would happen when using OptionT when I need to apply it to 3 models in this case?

Comment: Since this is explicitly about `OptionT`, maybe it should have a `scalaz` tag (and possibly also `monad-transformers` and/or `scala-cats`)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Some simple definitions for the sake of a complete working example:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

type User = String
type Location = String
type Address = String

case class UserProfile(user: User, location: Location, addresses: Address)

def getUserById(id: Long): Future[Option[User]] = id match {
  case 1 => Future.successful(Some("Foo McBar"))
  case _ => Future.successful(None)
}

def getLocationById(id: Long): Future[Option[Location]] = id match {
  case 1 => Future.successful(Some("The Moon"))
  case _ => Future.successful(None)
}

def getAddressById(id: Long): Future[Option[Address]] = id match {
  case 1 => Future.successful(Some("123 Moon St."))
  case _ => Future.successful(None)
}
```

And for the sake of completeness, here's what the Scalaz-free implementation would look like:

```
def getProfile(uid: Long, lid: Long, aid: Long): Future[Option[UserProfile]] =
  for {
    maybeUser     <- getUserById(uid)
    maybeLocation <- getLocationById(lid)
    maybeAddress  <- getAddressById(aid)
  } yield (
    for {
      user     <- maybeUser
      location <- maybeLocation
      address  <- maybeAddress
    } yield UserProfile(user, location, address)
  )
```

I.e. we have to nest for-comprehensions, just like we'd have to nest `map` to transform e.g. the `Int` value that might be inside a `Future[Option[Int]]`.

The `OptionT` monad transformer in Scalaz or Cats is designed to allow you to work with types like `Future[Option[A]]` without this nesting. For example you could write this:

```
import scalaz.OptionT, scalaz.std.scalaFuture._

def getProfile(uid: Long, lid: Long, aid: Long): OptionT[Future, UserProfile] =
  for {
    user     <- OptionT(getUserById(uid))
    location <- OptionT(getLocationById(lid))
    address  <- OptionT(getAddressById(aid))
  } yield UserProfile(user, location, address)
```

Or if you wanted a `Future[Option[UserProfile]]` you can just call `run`:

```
def getProfile(uid: Long, lid: Long, aid: Long): Future[Option[UserProfile]] = (
  for {
    user     <- OptionT(getUserById(uid))
    location <- OptionT(getLocationById(lid))
    address  <- OptionT(getAddressById(aid))
  } yield UserProfile(user, location, address)
).run
```

And then:

```
scala> getProfile(1L, 1L, 1L).foreach(println)
Some(UserProfile(Foo McBar,The Moon,123 Moon St.))
```

If any of the intermediate results are `None`, the whole thing will be `None`:

```
scala> getProfile(1L, 1L, 0L).foreach(println)
None

scala> getProfile(0L, 0L, 0L).foreach(println)
None
```

And of course if any of the requests fail, the whole thing fails with the first error.

As a footnote, if the requests don't depend on each other, you can compose them applicatively instead of monadically:

```
import scalaz.Scalaz._

def getProfile(uid: Long, lid: Long, aid: Long): Future[Option[UserProfile]] = (
  OptionT(getUserById(uid)) |@|
  OptionT(getLocationById(lid)) |@|
  OptionT(getAddressById(aid))
)(UserProfile.apply _).run
```

This models the computation more accurately and may be more efficient since it can run the requests in parallel.

Comment: That is what I call a home run man, thanks!    |@| is like Future.sequence?

Comment: @Blankman Yep—the big difference is that it works with different types (maintaining both the types and arity).

Comment: FYI: `Future.onSuccess` is deprecated since Scala 2.12
https://github.com/viktorklang/blog/blob/master/Futures-in-Scala-2.12-part-5.md

Comment: @TravisBrown I actually need to add another call, but it returns a Future[Seq[T]].  Is it possible to add this in now given the above?

Comment: @n4to4 Updated to use `foreach`.

Comment: @Blankman What semantics do you want? Does an empty sequence work like a `None`? I'd guess what you want is essentially to first transform that into a `Future[Option[Seq[T]]]`, but it probably merits a follow-up question with more details about the intent.

Comment: An empty sequeuence is just fine i.e. None will not cause the entire thing to return None.

Comment: I updated my question with the other property, which is a Future[Seq[Sale]].  This can be 0 or more results and 0 is fine.

Comment: @Blankman You can lift a `fss: Future[Seq[Sale]]` into an `OptionT[Future, Seq[Sale]]` with `fss.liftM[OptionT]`.